# Errors when changing Android version (Target Framework) in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a C# Xamarin Forms Solution in Visual Studio 2019 that was created from the  Xamarin Forms Template.

When the Android version (Target Framework), (found in the 'Application' Tab of the properties Window of the Android project) is set to either

1) Android 8.1 (Oreo)

2) Android 9.0 (Pie)

then my app works great on a phone running Android 9.0

However, as soon as I change it to 'Android 8.0 (Oreo)' then Visual Studio generates errors and warnings. Here is an image of them:

[image: Errors]

The reason I think I need to change the Android version to 8.0 is so that I can use the app on Android phones with this version. When I try to install the APK file (built targeting either 8.1 or 9.0) on an 8.0 Android device then the app does not work.

The error suggestion to "..increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion)..." seems odd considering I am trying to target a lower version.

I should point out that I have all the Android SDK's installed for 8.0/8.1/9.0 and all the Android SDK Build Tools.

What am I doing wrong? I am wanting to target Android 8.0 (Oreo).

I am very new to Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change the Minimum Android Version to run on lower API versions. Make Target Android version higher (to version 9) and Minimum Android Version to a version which you would like to support (maybe version 6). Also note that if you have any android support libraries or Xamarin.Forms, those also have a minimum build version. You have to target equal or higher version to build with those. Another thing you have to check is Supported Architectures (Properties-> Android Options -> Advanced -> Supported Architectures). Make sure it checked the architecture of the device that you try to deploy

Comment: thanks for your rely. Where would I find the minimum build version for Xamarin Forms for me to inspect / change it?

Comment: You can only change your project min android version and it's under the Project Properties -> Android Manifest. I suggest if you can always use the latest Xamarin.Forms package

Comment: Nalan, appreciate the advice.